# Getting data for a video fails

Tags: youtube-data-api

Using the following call:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=whatever&key=whatever

We get the following response:

```
{
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 755558787820 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=755558787820 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=755558787820"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 755558787820 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=755558787820 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
}
}
```

We checked the project (truthorange), and the Youtube Data API has been enabled (since 2017 or so). Everything was actually fine until 5/11, but starting with 5/12, this started failing for some reason.
Any ideas oh how to fix?

Comment: Have you visited the [link given](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=755558787820) ? If you are still experiencing this problem I would recommend you to try again from scratch even if it means recreating an account and so on.